# SAP Business one SDK require on client machine if addon developed using SAPBusinessOneSDK dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I am getting error class not register while installing my sap business one add-on. When I installed SAPBusinessOneSDK tools then it is working. So Is it mandatory to install SAP Business one SDK if add-on developed using SAP business one visual studio framework.

Comment: You should use SLD when deploying addons created in VS. http://my-tipss-trickss.blogspot.com/2015/10/creating-and-registering-add-on-package.html

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau, Sorry I don't understand your ans. Please describe..

Comment: I was showing you a link to another way of deploying addons instead of using .exe and .ard files.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau, I used  the same way of Add-On setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you use SAPBusinessOneSDK you must install it on every client machine, it's not enough pass it in the intaller, nether required because SAP calls the registered dll. You should implemented as policy install the sdk when clients are installed.